# Trying to compare array but getting "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

Can someone help me understand and correct my short code for the error in the title?

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
a = 2

def f(x):
    if x<0.5:
        return a*x
    elif x>=0.5:
        return a*(1-x)

plt.plot(x, f(x))
plt.show()
```

```
      6 
      7 def f(x):
----> 8     if x<0.5:
      9         return a*x
     10     elif x>=0.5:
```

---

Edit:

The plot should look like an upside-down V.
Trying np.piecewise():

```py
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
a = 2

y = np.piecewise(x, [x < 0.5, x >= 0.5], [a*x, a*(1-x)])

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

I get the error: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment cannot assign 100 input values to the 50 output values where the mask is true.

Comment: ``x`` is not just one single number, it is a list of number. Hence, you cannot compare a list to a number ``if x<0.5:``. If you want to compare it, you have to iterate through it. Like for example ``x = [0,  0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, ..., 1]``. How can you compare all of them to a single value of ``0.5``? But you can, of course, compare ``0 < 0.5 ``

Comment: Thanks, @Karina

Comment: @Karina It's not a list, it's an array. An array is comparable to a scalar, but converting the resulting array to a boolean is where it gets tricky.

Comment: What were you expecting `if x<0.5` to do? Maybe you want to check if any/all elements of `x` are less than 0.5? If so, did you try using `a.any()` or `a.all()` as the error recommends?

Comment: @wjandrea yes, right, it's an array. A slip of tongue (or finger? lol). Anyway, my point stays valid.

Comment: I guess the OP was expecting this: ``if 0.01 < 0.5: return a*0.01`` and then ``else: a* 0.6`` for example

Comment: @Karina How's that? You **can** compare an array to a scalar. Have you actually tried `x<0.5`? Cause you do actually get output: `array([True, True, True, ..., False, False, False])`

Comment: @wjandrea I know that ``x < 0.5`` will give output like that, but ``if x < 0.5:`` will not. And what the OP wants is actually just as simple as ``for i in range(len(x)): if x[i] < 0.5: return a*x`` something like that. In which case, a simple list would suffice, doesn't have to be an array.

Comment: Wanderer, what is the function supposed to do?  The argument is an array, but the if can only take one 'choice'.  It is a scalar operation.  Your question is incomplete.

Comment: @hpaulj, I was trying to plot the piecewise function f(x) for values from 0 to 1. The separation point was 0.5 between the two "returns" of the defined function. But my graph doesn't look right still after I changed "x<0.5" to "x.any()<0.5"

Comment: The third argument is supposed to be functions, not arrays.  But you could use those arrays in a `np.where`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `x` and the 2 derived arrays:

```
In [249]: x = np.linspace(0,1,11)
In [250]: x
Out[250]: array([0. , 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1. ])
In [251]: 2*x
Out[251]: array([0. , 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1. , 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2. ])
In [252]: 2*(1-x)
Out[252]: array([2. , 1.8, 1.6, 1.4, 1.2, 1. , 0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 0.2, 0. ])
```

One way to make a composite from the two, is to start with one array, and replace a subset of the values with other:

```
In [253]: res = 2*(1-x)
In [254]: res[x<.5] = 2*x[x<.5]
In [255]: res
Out[255]: array([0. , 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1. , 0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 0.2, 0. ])
```

`np.where` can be used to do the same:

```
In [256]: np.where(x<.5, 2*x, 2*(1-x))
Out[256]: array([0. , 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1. , 0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 0.2, 0. ])
```

We can use your `f`, but with scalar arguments:

```
In [261]: np.array([f(i) for i in x])
Out[261]: array([0. , 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1. , 0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 0.2, 0. ])
```

To use `piecewise` we have to provide functions, not whole arrays:

```
In [266]: np.piecewise(x, [x < 0.5, x >= 0.5], [lambda i:a*i, lambda i:a*(1-i)])
Out[266]: array([0. , 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1. , 0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 0.2, 0. ])
```

As for your original error:

```
In [267]: x<.5
Out[267]: 
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False,
       False, False])
In [268]: if (x<.5): print(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-268-f1475f5112fc>", line 1, in <module>
    if (x<.5): print(1)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

`if` is a plain python expression.  There's no implied iteration of the elements of `x`.  `if (x<.5).all():...` runs, but only tests if all the elements of `x` satisfy the condition.  That's not what you want.  Similarly for `any`.  The kind of `x<.5` masking that I did at the start is, perhaps a more common solution to this `ambiguity`.

A more direct translation of the `f(x)` switch, would be to calculate the `mask`, and apply it, and its complement to create the two parts of the result:

```
In [269]: mask = x<.5
In [270]: res = np.zeros_like(x)
In [271]: res
Out[271]: array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
In [272]: res[mask] = 2*x[mask]
In [273]: res[~mask] = 2*(1-x[~mask])
In [274]: res
Out[274]: array([0. , 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1. , 0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 0.2, 0. ])
```

or

```
In [275]: np.hstack((2*x[mask], 2*(1-x[~mask])))
Out[275]: array([0. , 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1. , 0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 0.2, 0. ])
```